# Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and $S,T\in A$ be normal. If $ST=TS$, then must $S^*T=TS^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I wish to show a kind of "simultaneous diagonalizability" statement for commuting normal operators $S,T\in\mathscr{L}(H)$ over a complex separable Hilbert space $H$. However, I've run into the hitch that even if $S$ and $T$ commute, I don't see why $S^*$ and $T$ should. So is it true that $ST=TS$ implies $S^*T=TS^*$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of this which I have seen goes like this. First a quick lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $S,T \in A$. Then, $ST=TS$ commute if and only if $e^{zS}T=Te^{zS}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> **Proof:** The forward implication follows from the series formula for $e^{zS}$. For the reverse implication, apply $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}$ to both sides of $e^{tS}T=Te^{tS}$.

Now the main result:

> **Fuglede's Theorem:** Let $S,T \in A$ with $S$ normal. Then $ST=TS$ if and only if $S^*T=TS^*$.
>
> **Proof:** It suffices to prove one direction. For notational convenience, I'll actually assume $S^*T=TS^*$. We need to show $e^{zS}Te^{-zS}=T$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We have
> $$e^{zS}Te^{-zS} = e^{zS} e^{-(z S)^*} T e^{(z S)^*} e^{-zS}=e^{zS-(zS)^*} T e^{-zS + (zS)^*}$$
> where the first equality uses $S^*T=TS^*$ and the lemma, and the second uses normality of $S$. But now note that $e^{zS-(zS)^*}$ (and its inverse) is unitary (since $zS-(zS)^*$ is anti-self-adjoint), and it follows that the right hand side is bounded (with norm identically equal to $\|T\|$). On the other hand, the left hand side is a holomorphic function of $z$, so the result follows from an appropriate version of Liouville's theorem.

**Added:** I found the place where I saw this argument. See Lemma 6.1 in these [lecture notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110660) of John Roe.

Comment: Very neat!  Very concisely explained too.

Comment: I really like your proof - it's much easier than the one I've seen so far! I've spotted a typo, though: the RHS of the first equality should read $e^{zS}e^{-(zS)^*}Te^{(zS)^*}e^{-zS}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @haemi: Thanks for the correction, I fixed it. To be clear, this is not my argument. I don't know whose argument it is originally, but I saw it some lecture notes of John Roe (linked above).

Comment: @MikeF Could you please see my similar question and thank you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656528/result-related-to-normal-operators?noredirect=1#comment5487334_2656528

Comment: @Student: I don't think things get any easier by taking both operators normal, instead of just one. The case of two commuting normal operators is really the most interesting case of Fuglede's theorem, and the only case to which I've ever seen the theorem applied. I view the fact that only one of the operators really needs to be normal in order for the proof to go through as "just a curiosity". However, I'd be happy to learn that I'm wrong and that the full strength of the theorem is actually needed for some interesting application.

Answer (score 6):

This result is not very trivial at all.  It is true, and this result is known as [Fuglede's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem) (in fact, Fuglede's theorem only requires that $S$ is a normal operator).